# SSIS Transformation: Why do I get Object not set to instance error, unless row wrapped in conditional statement

Tags: c#, ssis

I am accessing a text/flat file via `flat file source`: In the Transformation Task I have the `Input Column` as ZipCode and the Output Alias as: ZipCode. Usage Type: Read/Write:

I created an `Ouput Column`; tBookName.

The code looks like this:
This is simply an example of the behavior I have observed.
This mostly happens when I try to use certain methods like `Trim(` or `length`.

```
//This gives me an error message: 
//Object Not set to instance Of an object

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
string zipCode = (Row.ZipCode.Trim().lenght != 5 ? null : Row.ZipCode.Trim());
}


//This works: 
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.ZipCode))
{
string zipCode = (Row.ZipCode.Trim().lenght != 5 ? null : Row.ZipCode);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explore the autogenerated code, you'll see that ZipCode is not a primitive type, string. Instead it's a complex type/object because the base types don't support nulls, well not gracefully at least.

Instead, what they have chosen to do is to create a simple object that exposes an _IsNull extension/method/something to allow you to test for whether the type is null.

A more idiomatic way of writing your test would be (excluding the fact that I'm not testing for empty). You have a slightly special case since the string types have the isnullorempty and isnullorwhitespace methods to check for this. If you had other primitives to deal with, then you'd become very familiar with the _IsNull check.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (!Row.ZipCode_IsNull))
    {
        string zipCode = (Row.ZipCode.Trim().length != 5 ? null : Row.ZipCode);
    }
}
```

Sorry to all the .NET developers out there. My terminology is probably horrible dated. Feel free to edit this answer while I go sort my punch cards.

Comment: Thanks, so why do I have to check for null first?